# error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ

Tags: c++

Недавно начал изучать программирование и столкнулся с такой проблемой 
"error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ" после чего программа не собирается.  Много подобных тем видел но там достаточно большие проекты и сложные пути решения. Может в моем случае я просто что-то упустил?

Вот что выдает мне компилятор (VS 15).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

void main() {
    using SALES::Sales;
    Sales s1;
    Sales s2;
    double ar[] = { 56,23,78,45 };
    int n = 4;
    set_sales(s1);
    set_sales(s2, ar, n);
    show_Sales(s1);
    show_Sales(s2);
    system("pause");
}
```

Sales.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"
using namespace SALES;
void set_sales(Sales & s, const double ar[], int n) {
    s.average = 0;
    s.max = ar[0];
    s.min = ar[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        s.sales[i] = ar[i];
        s.average += ar[i];
        if (s.max < ar[i])
            s.max = ar[i];
        if (s.min > ar[i])
            s.min = ar[i];
    }
    s.average /= n;
}
void set_sales(Sales & s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < QUARTERS; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter 4 sales: " << i + 1 << " quarter: ";
        std::cin >> s.sales[i];
    }
    s.average = 0;
    s.max = s.sales[0];
    s.min = s.sales[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        s.average += s.sales[i];
        if (s.max < s.sales[i])
            s.max = s.sales[i];
        if (s.min > s.sales[i])
            s.min = s.sales[i];
    }
    s.average /= 4;
}

void show_Sales(const Sales & s) {
    std::cout << "MAX = " << s.max << std::endl;
    std::cout << "MIN = " << s.min << std::endl;
    std::cout << "AVERAGE = " << s.average << std::endl;
}
```

Header.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED

namespace SALES {
    const int QUARTERS = 4;
    struct Sales {
        double sales[QUARTERS];
        double average;
        double max;
        double min;
    };
    void set_sales(Sales & s, const double ar[], int n);
    void set_sales(Sales & s);      
    void show_Sales(const Sales & s);
 } 
#endif // HEADER_H_INCLUDED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функции вы объявили в `namespace SALES`:

```
namespace SALES {
    // ...
    void set_sales(Sales & s, const double ar[], int n);
    void set_sales(Sales & s);      
    void show_Sales(const Sales & s);
}
```

А определили в глобальном пространстве имен. С точки зрения компилятора это совершенно другие функции, в другом пространстве имен.

То, что вы написали `using namespace SALES;` в начале Sales.cpp, не переносит ваши определения в `namespace SALES`.

Вам нужно либо обернуть и определения функций тоже в `namespace SALES { ... }`, либо определять их по полному имени:

```
void SALES::set_sales(Sales & s, const double ar[], int n) {
    ...
}
```

В любом случае, `using namespace SALES;` в Sales.cpp не нужен.